# Can't get fetch(url) working in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to retrieve the json response from api url using fetch (method : GET) in react-native.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {jsonData: {}};
  }

componentWillMount() {
    console.log("inside componentWillMount");

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/listData')
        .then((response) => {console.log('response: '); return response.json();})
        .then((responseJson) => {console.log('responseData: '+JSON.stringify(responseJson)); return this.setState({jsonData: responseJson});})
        .catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
  }
```

The api returns data in this format:

```
{
        object: 'list',
        data: [...]
}
```

The api url works via curl. I also tried to run the fetch part of the code standalone using node by installing node-fetch and it printed the responseData properly.
But, in react-native, it doesn't print any of the console log statements inside the then function of fetch nor does it set the state of jsonData.

Could you please tell me what could be the problem? I have been googling around for quite a long time trying to find what could be the issue.

---

**EDIT**
I tried the async fetch as follows:

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.log("inside componentWillMount");
    this.fetchData().done();
}
async fetchData(){
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/listData')
    const json = await response.json();
    const data = json.url;

    console.log('data'+url);
}
```

Still, the same issue persists.
I am not able to understand why it works with the facebook url and not my local api url

---

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to Michael Cheng for pointing me in the right direction. 
I found this link : 
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/154 .

**Code Fix:**
I just replaced the localhost with my ipv4 address as http://myserveripv4address:3000/listData and it worked.

**Version:**

react-native@0.50.4

**Device :** Android

Comment: 1. Since it looks like you are testing on a locally run server, do the server logs say the fetch request was received? 2. This looks to be an error: `return this.setState({jsonData: responseJson});` I don't know why you are returning the `setState` call. Rewrite it as `this.setState({jsonData: responseJson}); return;`

Comment: You were right about the fetch request Michael. There was nothing in the local server logs for fetch request.

Comment: I have updated the setState as you have mentioned. The same issue is still there. I also noticed in the device logs this error with my local api url : 'Network request failed
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\whatwg-fetch\fetch.js:441:29 in onerror'. I googled this error and it seems when there is a timeout, this error is thrown.  I replaced the local api url with 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json' just for testing purpose and fetch worked. So, the issue is when the local api url is called in fetch. I am testing in android. I also tried async. Still the same issue

Comment: the curl and the standalone fetch code using the local api url works but it doesn't work in react-native

Comment: Many thanks Michael Cheng for pointing me in the right direction. I found this link : https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/154 . I just replaced the localhost with my ipv4 address and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

some ideas:

- if is iOS, you need the remote url to be https or disable this security feature;
- You may need to mark your fetch() as async function;
- Try to make an async fetch w/o promise.

Comment: most likely is the `https` policy on iOS, I remember spending quite some time to figure that out.